# Size the content of an IFrame or use an alternative

Tags: javascript, iframe, resize

I have say 6 aspx pages that I want to display within something like an Iframe so that when I look at the page I can see an array of controls that contain a web page.

But if I use an Iframe I cannot then size the content to the size of the Iframe although YouTube does resize the content so their must be a way to do so.

So, how would I go about making sure that the content fits the IFrame or is there a better way of doing this.
Also, ultimately I would like to go to the page if the control was clicked but I am not sure that the Iframe has a click event.

So, how would I go about doing that ?

Comment: Security policys typically don't allow to calculate the size of some iframe's content. However, iframe and host window can communicate with javascript messages. It's a popular problem for iframe's with external addresses and typically people use the max. possible size (e.g. 2000px) to make sure everything fits in worst case.

Answer (score 0):

If the contents of the iframe are on the same URL as the main page then you shouldn't have any security issues and you can add JavaScript to the content pages to pass the height of their content back to the main page. Same with click events: you can have some JavaScript call a function on the parent page.

Here's an example of a main and iframe content page. The content page has a button you can click that will resize the iframe based on the height of the content.

main.htm

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function resize1(h) {
    document.getElementById("iframe1").height = h + 50;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>Test</div>
<iframe id="iframe1" border="1" height="100" src="iframe.htm" width="200">
</body>
```

iframe.htm

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="parent.resize1(document.getElementById('content').clientHeight);">Resize iframe</a>
<div id="content" style="background:Red;height:500;width:50px;">
    Test content
</div>
</body>
```

You could adapt this to suit your needs. For example, the height could be set as soon as the iframe content loads by calling the function in the onload event of the iframe content page.

Note that any JavaScript functions you want to call on the main page must be in the HEAD section.